# Configuring Google Cloud error monitoring notifications via GCloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-monitoring

I wish to report uncaught Firebase functions errors to a Slack channel in all of my Firebase projects. Preferably by using the Google Cloud Error Monitoring feature so I can mark errors as resolved, filter by occurences, etc.

I have managed to automate creating the notification channel via the gcloud CLI whenever I create a new project.

I am able to get errors to show up by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/errors?project=<my_project_id>, clicking 'configure notifications' and selecting my notification channel.

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing via the CLI or the API so I can automate this step?

The manual process on the console does not seem to create a monitoring policy.

Comment: Can you check the below links related to use of API. [https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference) [https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api)

Comment: cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api
I am already using this API to create the notification channel. The part I can't find is how I can connect the notification channel to error-monitoring.

cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference
This gives me a couple of read operations and lets me:
- Report a new error event
- Update an error group's tracking issues

Neither of these seem intuitively to be what I'm looking for. Unless updating an error group's tracking issue somehow forwards all Firebase functions errors to a notification channel?

Comment: Does the errors appear at monitoring? If so go to alerting and create policy.

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting > click on error itself > View logs > You will be at logs explorer (look for create alert)
[image]

The above can be automated with [terraform as an example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy.html)

Comment: I am only interested in automation as this is meant to be set up automatically for all errors whenever a new project is created.
The terraform example shows how to create a monitoring policy, which is not the same as the manual proces of going to the error-monitoring and configuring notifications. I can't find anything that would, for example, trigger a notification when a previously resolved error reoccurs.

Comment: If you want to catch specific errors then go through Logging > log-based metrics

Comment: That doesn't give the same built-in support as error reporting (like grouping errors, marking them as resolved, getting a link to the error in error-reporting console etc.). I'm looking for an automated way of doing what I described in the original post.